# EF Core 7 can not translate query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I wrote these two queries:

```
var query1 = await db.Table1.AsNoTracking()
                     .Where(x => x.Id == 50)
                     .Select(x => new query { x.Id, x.F1, x.F2 }).ToListAsync();

var query2 = await db.Table2.AsNoTracking()
                     .Where(y => y.Id == 80 && !query1.Any(z => z.F1 == y.F1))
                     .Select(y => new query { y.Id, y.F1, y.F2 })
                     .ToListAsync();
```

But EF Core 7 says that it cannot translate `query1.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id))`.

But this code is working in other versions. What would be the right way to write it in order for EF Core 7 to translate it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `query1` is a `List` of anonymous objects with properties `F1` and `F2`. They do not have an `Id` property.

Comment: I did the correction, but the result is the same thing.  EF Core 7, cannot translate it.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you would need to include `Id` in the *projection* from the first query:

```
var query1 = await db.Table1.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(x => x.Id == 50)
                            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.F1, x.F2})
                            .ToListAsync();

var query2 = await db.Table2.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(y => y.Id == 80 && !query1.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id))
                            .Select(y => new {y.F1, y.F2, y.F3})
                            .ToListAsync();
```

This is not specific to any version of .net or EF. You might not have included the projection of `query1` in previous versions of the code.

---

Interestingly, the subquery against the results of `query1` will never match, because you have specified that Id *MUST* be 80 in `query2` and in `query1` you have specified Id *MUST* be 50. So there is no point to negating the results of `query1` at all!

The following will have the same result:

```
var query2 = await db.Table2.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(y => y.Id == 80)
                            .Select(y => new {y.F1, y.F2, y.F3})
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: They are correct, you can filter different id in both query.  But the second one I would like not to contain the same Id like the first one.  And I wouldn't like to use Contain instead of Any.

Comment: They are two different table with different rows and records.  But table2 could contain some value equal to table1.  The Id of the table2 if different from the table1.

Comment: When the filter values are dynamic or parameterised, then your initial request makes more sense, If that is the case, you really should use parameters in your example though to make it clear that the specific value of the Id match is arbitrary. Many posts on SO are misunderstandings on OP, with those specific values for Id this post is in danger of being put in the PICNIC category ;) More importantly though, your linq query cannot be dynamic without parameters.

Comment: What it looks like you have done is modify the query for the sake of posting here, and then made a broad statement "this works in previous versions..." when in fact the query in your code is different. Big red flag, in the future you need to post the query exactly as it is in your code, or create an [mcve] that fully demonstrates the issue.